# How to pick a value in a column based on row number within a pipeline

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

This question is more to help me with constructing an efficient pipeline for my code.

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                 Date = c("2015-10-26", "2015-10-26", "2015-10-26", "2015-10-26",
                          "2015-10-27", "2015-10-27", "2015-10-27"),
                 Ticker = c("ANZ", "CBA", "NAB", "WBC", "ANZ", "CBA", "WBC"),
                 Open = c(29.11, 77.89, 32.69, 31.87, 29.05, 77.61, 31.84),
                 High = c(29.17, 77.93, 32.76, 31.92, 29.08, 78.1, 31.95),
                 Low = c(28.89, 77.37, 32.42, 31.71, 28.9, 77.54, 31.65),
                 Close = c(28.9, 77.5, 32.42, 31.84, 28.94, 77.74, 31.77),
                 Volume = c(6350170L, 2251288L, 3804239L, 5597684L, 5925519L, 2424679L,
                            5448863L)
)
```

#### This is what I'd like my workflow to look like

```
df %>%
  mutate(new column = some_function(Open, 1))  # "Open" is column name, "1" is for row no.
```

Which should out put the following:

```
Date         Ticker  Open  High   Low Close  Volume new_column
1 2015-10-26    ANZ 29.11 29.17 28.89 28.90 6350170      29.11
2 2015-10-26    CBA 77.89 77.93 77.37 77.50 2251288      29.11
3 2015-10-26    NAB 32.69 32.76 32.42 32.42 3804239      29.11
4 2015-10-26    WBC 31.87 31.92 31.71 31.84 5597684      29.11
5 2015-10-27    ANZ 29.05 29.08 28.90 28.94 5925519      29.11
6 2015-10-27    CBA 77.61 78.10 77.54 77.74 2424679      29.11
7 2015-10-27    WBC 31.84 31.95 31.65 31.77 5448863      29.11
```

Any ideas what the `some_function` would be within `tidyverse`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think OP wants to specify *any* row number, not just the first element. But you can simply do this using the standard `[` subset operator:

```r
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                 Date = c("2015-10-26", "2015-10-26", "2015-10-26", "2015-10-26",
                          "2015-10-27", "2015-10-27", "2015-10-27"),
                 Ticker = c("ANZ", "CBA", "NAB", "WBC", "ANZ", "CBA", "WBC"),
                 Open = c(29.11, 77.89, 32.69, 31.87, 29.05, 77.61, 31.84),
                 High = c(29.17, 77.93, 32.76, 31.92, 29.08, 78.1, 31.95),
                 Low = c(28.89, 77.37, 32.42, 31.71, 28.9, 77.54, 31.65),
                 Close = c(28.9, 77.5, 32.42, 31.84, 28.94, 77.74, 31.77),
                 Volume = c(6350170L, 2251288L, 3804239L, 5597684L, 5925519L, 2424679L,
                            5448863L)
)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(new_column = Open[5])
#>         Date Ticker  Open  High   Low Close  Volume new_column
#> 1 2015-10-26    ANZ 29.11 29.17 28.89 28.90 6350170      29.05
#> 2 2015-10-26    CBA 77.89 77.93 77.37 77.50 2251288      29.05
#> 3 2015-10-26    NAB 32.69 32.76 32.42 32.42 3804239      29.05
#> 4 2015-10-26    WBC 31.87 31.92 31.71 31.84 5597684      29.05
#> 5 2015-10-27    ANZ 29.05 29.08 28.90 28.94 5925519      29.05
#> 6 2015-10-27    CBA 77.61 78.10 77.54 77.74 2424679      29.05
#> 7 2015-10-27    WBC 31.84 31.95 31.65 31.77 5448863      29.05
```

Created on 2018-03-16 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 2):

looking for `head`?

```
df %>%
  mutate(newcolumn = head(Open, 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be to use just `first` function itself. If OP is looking for a function from `dplyr` which can provide value from a row then that function should be `nth`.

```
df %>%
    mutate(newcolumn = first(Open))
```

OR for value from a particular row

```
df %>%
      mutate(newcolumn = nth(Open, 5))
```

`nth` is a `dplyr` function.